# Using move semantics on structures with std::string members

Tags: c++, c++11, move, stdstring

Question might be trivial, but I didn't find any relevant answer yet. My example code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct ExampleStruct {
  int a;
  std::string b;
  double c;
};

ExampleStruct&& getExampleStruct() {
  ExampleStruct obj;
  obj.a = 1;
  obj.b = std::string("asdf");
  obj.c = 1.43;

  return std::move(obj);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
  ExampleStruct&& moved_obj = getExampleStruct();

  // moved_obj.a == 1
  // moved_obj.b == ""
  // moved_obj.c == 1.43

  return 0;
}
```

Why is `moved_obj.b` emptied, while `moved_obj.a` and `moved_obj.c` remained the same?

Comment: How do you empty an `int` or a `double`?

Comment: You're returning a reference to a local variable. Accessing anything in `moved_obj` is undefined behavior.

Comment: The semantics of assigning an rvalue to a fundamental type is to copy the value.

Comment: Mat, I belived that returning reference to rvalue using std::move (C++11) semantics prolong lifetime of an object, am I wrong?

Comment: @igleyy [class.temporary]/5 "The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement is not
extended; the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in the return statement."

Comment: It means that I didn't get idea of std::move. I understand now why my code above does not work. Could you explain me, why such snippet does not work? s variable is empty.

    auto s = getExampleStruct().b;

Comment: @igleyy What do you mean by *does not work*? With the code above, accessing `.b` of the returned reference is Undefined Behaviour, as the reference refers to an already destroyed object.

Comment: You need to watch [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-9-of-n), urgently.

Comment: @DyP I understand that using reference to already destroyed object yields Undefined Behaviour. I thought that using std::move prolongs lifetime of object inside getExampleStruct. Clearly I was wrong and I don't quite get std::move yet.

Comment: @igleyy `std::move` is just a "cast" that changes the value category of an expression: e.g. if *expression* is an lvalue, then `std::move(` *expression* `)` is an xvalue (i.e. rvalue and glvalue). In itself, it doesn't do anything but a `static_cast<some_type&&>(` *expression* `)`, where `some_type` is the type of *expression*. The actual movement happens inside the move ctor and move assignment operator.

Comment: @DyP that made things clear for me and video linked by FredOverflow helped too. Thank you for your help.